# Запрет передачи нескольких значений параметру main

Tags: c++, boost

Как в `boost.program_options` запретить передачу нескольких значений одному параметру или передачу значения вообще? Ниже приведён первый пример [туториала](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) из документации. Используя его, можно вызвать `program --compression 1 2` или `program --help 1` без исключений (compression будет равен 1; help сообщение появится). Хотелось бы, чтобы такие параметры считались ошибочными.

```
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);    

if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    return 1;
}

if (vm.count("compression")) {
    cout << "Compression level was set to " 
 << vm["compression"].as<int>() << ".\n";
} else {
    cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
}
```

Comment: Сделайте цикл по параметрам, с кейсами, и счётчик (или булевскую) в `case` на каждый параметр, которая будет считать 0 раз вошли в параметр или 1 раз. Если счетчик не равен нулю - параметр ошибочный.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну я специально использую готовую либу для парсинга параметров, чтобы самому не писать циклы, свитчи и т.п.. Можно ли с помощью boost.program_options это сделать?

Comment: По идее для этого достаточно было бы сделать `("help", po::bool_switch(), "produce help message")`, `bool_switch` сделан специально для булевых аргументов, после которых не следует значение. Однако (как и многое другое в этой библиотеке) этот механизм сломан и следующее значение будет сохранено как значение без имени. Так что тут наверное не обойтись без кастомного валидатора. Или без проверки на наличие параметров без имени. Лично я бы не стал пользоваться этой библиотекой.

Comment: @VTT можете предложить библиотеку лучше? В проекте уже используется boost, поэтому сразу выбор пал на неё, но это непринципиально

Comment: К сожалению, на примете ничего подходящего не видно

Comment: как один из вариантов: https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts в виде одного заголовочного файла, довольно удобная вещь

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan по синтаксису похоже, что то же самое

Comment: Посмотрите [argp_parse](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp)